# How to call method in a row through loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

I have to call it 5 times so it would print like this.

run:

I will call this routine 5 times and so on...

```
public class Method2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        call();
    }
    static void call(){
        System.out.println("I will call this routine 5 times");
        for (int = i = 1; i<5; i++); //I don't know what I'm doing here.
    }
}
```

I am new to method, I can call but I don't know how to put it in a loop.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: It's a Java for loop... just look at tutorials: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html
These are just the very basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `println` call has to happen *inside* the loop:

```
static void call(){
    for (int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
        System.out.println("I will call this routine 5 times");
    }
}
```

Your code sets up an initial condition (`i=1`); a condition that must be satisfied for each run of the loop (`i<=5`); and an operation to happen at the end of each run of the loop (`i++`).

Inside the loop (delimited by `{` and `}`) is the `println` call, which happens five times.

One more stylistic note: most programmers would write the loop as starting from 0, and going up to (but not including) 5, like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) { ... }
```

This is just because for most computing tasks it's more helpful if things are numbered from 0 rather than from 1. But it doesn't matter much here, because you're not using the value of `i` for anything other than looping.

And an additional consideration: you talk about *calling a routine* five times. If you mean that you want the entire `call()` method to be invoked five times, then you'd want your loop to sit inside the `main()` method that invokes it, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
        call();
    }
}
static void call(){
    System.out.println("I will call this routine 5 times");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's how for loop works ..

```
for (initialization; condition; increment/decrement) {
    statement(s) //block of statements
}
```

> so you actually need to place your print statement in `{}`

```
static void call() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("I will call this routine 5 times");
        }
}
```

If you want to print your statement **5 times**, you either need to start your loop

> from 0 to 5 (exclusive), like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

}
```

> or from 1 to 5 (inclusive)

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

well in C# it would look like this with for:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Here is the text 5 times");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

and this would be the same with while:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i=0;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Here is the text 5 times");
                i++;
            }
            while (i < 5);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```